# NextJS Hydration Error - Hydration failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui, hydration

I'm using `NextLink` with my project to creat links, however it seems using NextLink returns this error `Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.`

Now upon checking the console this is what i'm getting as error: `Expected server HTML to contain a matching <a> in <a>.`
This doesn't happen when I change to `Link` .

Here is the code that's making the error:

```
<Box flex={1} align="right">
      <Box ml={2} display={{ base: 'inline-block', md: 'none' }}>
        <Menu>
          <MenuButton
            as={IconButton}
            icon={<HamburgerIcon />}
            variant="outline"
            aria-label="Options"
          />
          <MenuList>
            <NextLink href="/" passHref>
              <MenuItem as={Link}> About</MenuItem>
            </NextLink>
            <NextLink href="/" passHref>
              <MenuItem as={Link}> Work</MenuItem>
            </NextLink>
          </MenuList>
        </Menu>
      </Box>
    </Box>
```

Comment: I'm using ChakraUI

Comment: I think the issue is caused by the wrapping of Chakra's `MenuItem` with Next.js' `Link` component. You can try setting `MenuItem`'s `as` prop to `NextLink` instead.

Answer (score 0):

While rendering your application, there was a difference between the React tree that was pre-rendered from the server and the React tree that was rendered during the first render in the browser (hydration).

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35224966)